# Apache rewrite_mod: RewriteRule path and query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case-sensitive

I currently have a website with a standard web interface on `index.php`, and I made an iPhone-friendly version in `iphone.php`.
Both pages handle the same arguments.

It works fine when I *manually* go to `.../iphone.php`, but I'd like to *rewrite* anything on `.../path/` and `.../path/index.php` to `iphone.php` if `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` contains `mobile`, and optionally add the query string (not sure if/when I'd need to add it).

So far, this is what I have in my `.../path/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.+mobile.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule index.php?(.*) iphone.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule index.php      iphone.php [L]
```

The problems are, it matches `index.php` in *any subfolder*, and it won't match `.../path/?args`…

Comment: Do you have one page index.php or many in various folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `RewriteCond` is applied to exactly one rewrite rule.
2. To match all user agents containing 'mobile' in it's name `.*` - 0 or more any character should be used in `^.+mobile.+$` statement.
3. `RewriteRule` by default doesn't include query string - `[QSA]` flag should be used to include query string.
4. `RewriteRule` uses regexp - you should use `\.` to escape dots.
5. `RewriteRule` automatically saves query string the same, if not specified another.

**UPDATED:**

Complete **.htacess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php $1iphone.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1iphone.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all those clarifications, but this does not resolve my main concern: `.../path/?args` is still not handled…

Comment: I've added possible fix of this problem. Do you need to rewrite `.../path?args` (without trailing slash) too?

Comment: I did try that, but Apache returns a 500 when I do.  My guess is `^(.*)$` goes in some kind of a loop, and never gets out.

Comment: You're right. I've added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*iphone\.php.*` to prevent loop. It's strange to me that `[L]` seems not work.

Comment: For a second here, I thought you had _the_ solution... It does help with the `/?` problem, but any other requested URI (like, say, my `style.css`) now returns a 404 :(
There has to be some way to match `.../?` without matching everything... The only option I see is to counter-match every request URI I still need to let through

Comment: To prevent rewriting existing files I've added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` (sounds like not existings file) for `^(.*)$` rewrite rule.

Comment: It works !
Thank you very much, you saved me quite a lot of tries and testings :)

Comment: Actually, we don't need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*iphone\.php` anymore, as it's taken care of by `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `iphone.php` has to be a file for the whole thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule /path/index.php /path/iphone.php [QSA,L]
```

EDIT: QSA is `Query string append`, so you don't need to handle that differently. If you want you can add an extra parameter too, like:

```
RewriteRule /path/index.php /path/iphone.php?extra=param [QSA,L]
```